# background watermark image size in visualforce pdf

Tags: visualforce, css, html

I am trying to add watermark across all pages of vf page document however the image size becomes too large and overflows all the pages. Below is my code

```
<style>
     <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(OR(qObj.SBQQ__Status__c='Pending',qObj.SBQQ__Status__c='Awaiting Approval'),true,false)}">
                  
                    @page {
                        background: url("{!$Label.QuoteDraftURL}") ;
                        background-position: center;
                        background-repeat: repeat;
                    }
      </apex:outputText>
</style>
```

however when i try to use below code even then the size doesnt change.

```
<style>
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(OR(qObj.SBQQ__Status__c='Pending',qObj.SBQQ__Status__c='Awaiting Approval'),true,false)}">
                  
                    @page {
                        background: url("{!$Label.QuoteDraftURL}") center/50px 50px repeat !important;
                        background-position: center;
                        background-repeat: repeat;
                        width: 90%;
                        height: 90%;
                        top: 20%;
                        left: 10%;
                        background-size: 50px 50px;
                    }
      </apex:outputText>
</style>
```

how to make sure the watermark doesnt overflow?
PS: tried contain inside background-size but that didnt change anything.